# Powershell API & Pagination issue

Tags: powershell, rest, pagination

I'm querying the Symantec API for he product "Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager (SEPM)". Based on the documentation [here](https://apidocs.securitycloud.symantec.com/#/doc?id=computers). The issue is it seems I'm always getting the first page, and am wondering where I got it wrong

using the following code :

```
$URI = $script:BaseURL + '/computers'
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $script:accessToken.token
    'Content'       = 'application/json'
}
$body = @{
    ComputerName = '*'
    sort         = 'COMPUTER_ID'
    pageIndex    = 1
    pageSize     = 100
}
$allResults = @()
do {
    try {
        # Invoke the request params
        $params = @{
            Method  = 'GET'
            Uri     = $URI
            headers = $headers
            Body    = ($body | ConvertTo-Json)
        }
        $resp = Invoke-RestMethod @params -SkipCertificateCheck
        $allResults += $resp.content
        $body.pageIndex++
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning -Message "Error: $_"
    }
} until ($body.pageIndex -eq $resp.totalPages)
```

I'm just incrementing the pageindex and every query I make is correctly incremented, but I always get the following result with `firstPage = $true` no matter of the pageIndex increment

```
PS C:\> $resp | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty "content"    

size             : 20
number           : 0
sort             : {@{direction=ASC; property=COMPUTER_NAME; ascending=True}}
numberOfElements : 20
totalElements    : 262
totalPages       : 14
lastPage         : False
firstPage        : True
```

Also tried to increment and set `until ($resp.lastpage -eq $true)` but I'm stuck in an infinite loop

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have the documentation for that API available to review?

Comment: The documentation link doesn’t display very well on a phone, but maybe the “parameters” table is querystring parameters rather than body content? Especially as the method is GET…

Comment: Good call mclayton ! It was indeed querystrings with the GET method. I just tried and managed to get the pagination working. Thank you ! 
I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by mclayton, query parameters shouldn't be passed as `body` with the `GET` method but as query strings to the URI

Fixed it with the following code (commenting for detailed explanation)

```
$URI = $script:BaseURL + '/computers'

$allResults = @()
$headers = @{
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $script:accessToken.token
    'Content'       = 'application/json'
}

# Query strings from a hashtable
$QueryStrings = @{
    ComputerName = '*'
    sort      = 'COMPUTER_ID'
    pageIndex = 1
    pageSize  = 100
}

# Contruct the URI
$builder = New-Object System.UriBuilder($URI)
$query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($builder.Query)
# Parse the query strings and add the parameters
foreach ($param in $QueryStrings.GetEnumerator()) {
    $query[$param.Key] = $param.Value
}
$builder.Query = $query.ToString()
$URI = $builder.ToString()

do {
    try {
        # Invoke the request params
        $params = @{
            Method  = 'GET'
            Uri     = $URI
            headers = $headers
            # Body    = ($body | ConvertTo-Json) # removed body
        }
        $resp = Invoke-RestMethod @params -SkipCertificateCheck
        $allResults += $resp.content

        # Increment the page index & update URI
        $QueryStrings.pageIndex++
        $query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($builder.Query)
        foreach ($param in $QueryStrings.GetEnumerator()) {
            $query[$param.Key] = $param.Value
        }
        $builder.Query = $query.ToString()
        $URI = $builder.ToString()

    } catch {
        Write-Warning -Message 'Error: $_'
    }

# pagination until last page provided by the API
} until ($resp.lastPage -eq $true)
```